# Check Box Value Passed In FormCollection MVC Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a FormCollection being passed back to a controller, which is processed, however, the value passed back if its true is `'true,false'` but if it's unchecked it's just `'false'`. My field uses iChecks.

My object that is being built is as follows:

`field.IsSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(form["Field.IsChecked"]);`

What would be the best method to get the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing :

`form["Field.IsChecked"].Contains("true")`
Which already returns a bool so you dont have to convert.

OR

You could go:

`Convert.ToBoolean(form["Field.IsChecked"].Split(',').First());`
or
`Convert.ToBoolean(form["Field.IsChecked"].Split(',')[0]);`

Comment: Option one works like a charm thanks! Thanks for the swift help.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use the Model Binder for this purpose, it is the right way for doing this nowadays, you can simply add a boolean property to your model class, and then use the checkbox helper of MVC.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And your ActionMethod:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
    field.IsSelected = viewModel.IsChecked;
}
```

And your view something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "YourController", FormMethod.Post)) 
{

    <div>  
        @Html.CheckBox("IsChecked")
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

Comment: Good day Salah, Thank you for your assistance. Under normal circumstances, I would implement my checkbox accordingly but I'm in the process of patching a bug on a legacy system that uses FormCollections, and as much as I would love to change it use Model Binding time is against me here.

Again, thank you for your assistance, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Convert.ToBoolean(form["Field.IsChecked"].Split(',').First());
```